pruning attention heads based on attention maps - transformers
i was randomly fooling around with llama 3.1 and trying to generate attention maps for different layer-header combo's and realized that a few layer-header combos consistently had much lower weights compared to their peers in the same layer. I thought maybe if we could repeat this experiment with 100k different sentences and figure out if some layer-head combos persistently have much lower weights than peers, then these could be candidates for pruning ? maybe stupid but its worth putting out in the community to get a better perspective
